# Fill dataframe column repeating row values in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to fill a data frame column with a vector, need to repeat the vector values before passing to the next vector value like this. I work in R.

```
NEW_COLUMN=c(1,2)
```

Original data frame example

```
A B C    A B C NEW_COLUMN
X X X    X X X 1
X X X    X X X 1
X X X    X X X 2
X X X    X X X 2
```

Comment: Look what the `each` argument does in `?rep`

Answer (score 1):

You could try it like this:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4),
             b = c(4,5,6,7),
             c = c(7,8,9,10))

newcol <- c(1,2)

#instert new column by repeating each element in vector "newcol" 2 times
df2 <- dplyr::mutate(df, d = rep(newcol, each = 2))

df2
```